# err="contract creation code storage out of gas"

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts, quorum

I try to deploy a really simple smart contract with remix

```
       contract SimpleStorage2 {
             uint public storedData;

             constructor (uint initVal) public {
             storedData = initVal;
             }

       function set(uint x) public {
                storedData = x;
             } 

       function get() view public returns (uint retVal) {
       return storedData;
       }
       }
```

It seems that everything is fine when I execute deploy but when i consult the node.log it appears :

```
        VM returned with error   err="contract creation code storage 
        out of gas"
```

Do anyone have an idea about this problem
Ps: I'am running a local network with 4 nodes and I'am allocating eth  to account.

Do anyone have an idea about the problem:

here is my genesis.json

```
                     {
       "alloc": {
          "0xed9d02e382b34818e88b88a309c7fe71e65f419d": {
             "balance": "1000000000000000000000000000"

        },
        "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "config": {
        "homesteadBlock": 0,
        "byzantiumBlock": 0,
        "chainId": 10,
        "eip150Block": 0,
        "eip155Block": 0,
        "eip150Hash": 
        "0x000000
        0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "eip158Block": 0,
        "isQuorum": true
        },
        "difficulty": "0x0",
        "extraData": 
        "0x0000000000000000000
        000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "gasLimit": "0xE0000000",
        "mixhash": "0x00000000000000
        000000000000000000000000647572616c65787365646c6578",
        "nonce": "0x0",
        "parentHash": "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000
        0000000000000000000000000000",
        "timestamp": "0x00"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but for anyone stuck like me, it could be that you're using a newer version of the Solidity compiler while your geth version supports an older version.